# I want to switch the speed with a click of a button on my script

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a marco that pulls the mouse down slowly and I want to have the option to swich speeds with a click of a button but the script only switches when the button is set on the middle mouse button and no where else how do i make it to where I can set it to anything on the keyboard or the side buttons on the scroll wheel

```
-- Speed settings
local speed1 = 2  -- Speed setting 1
local speed2 = 5  -- Speed setting 2
local currentSpeed = speed1  -- Current speed setting

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    end

    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 then
        ToggleSpeed()
    end

    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
        if IsKeyLockOn("scrolllock") and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(0, currentSpeed)
                Sleep(13)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
        end
     end
 end

-- Function to toggle between speed settings
function ToggleSpeed()
    if currentSpeed == speed1 then
        currentSpeed = speed2
    else
        currentSpeed = speed1
    end
end
```

Comment: You should customize the condition above `ToggleSpeed()`.  Currently it handles RMB, which is incorrect (RMB is already used by the "main switcher" of the script).  You may change `and arg == 2` -> `and arg == 3` for MMB or `4` for Back mouse button or `5` for Forward mouse button or any number starting from `6` for extra mouse buttons.  You can not handle keyboard keys (except special G-keys on Logitech keyboard which needs `event == "G_PRESSED"`).